# How to install a react-three/fiber and react-three/drei version compatible with "react": "^17.0.2"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I having trouble with the installation of react-three/fiber and react-three/drei. Please tell me how to install a downgrade version of the two packages. I can't change the version of my react and react-dom because some packages might be affected by the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target a specific version in the package.json file, try something like this:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
...
  "@react-three/fiber": "7.0.6"
  "@react-trhee/drei": "7.5.1"
...
}
```

After the changes you will have to delete the `node_modules` and reinstall

Alternatively if you already uninstall/remove the packages, you can target specific versions by doing:

```
npm install [package]@[version]
```

or

```
yarn add [package]@[version]
```

For eaxmple `npm install @react-three/fiber@7.0.6`